# Scraping days and months from a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup

I am to scrap all dates and month of some events from a given website.
There is a special class (for example let's look how days are written):

```
<span class="date-day">28</span>
```

My code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
temp_1 = soup_2.find_all('span', class_ = 'date-day')
event_day = []
for a in temp_1:
    event_day.append(a['date-day'])
```

However there is a **KeyError** which I guess mean that something is wrong with *event_day.append(a['date-day'])* this part.
How should the proper key look like?
And what is the key for months?

---

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530033/python-scraping-date-from-html-page-june-10-2017) but the solution completely doesn't match my problem (or maybe my code is wrong but similar way worked with scraping links and for some alternative texts).

Comment: Hard to know exactly without seeing the HTML structure but I would remove `['date-day']` from the `append`. I believe `temp_1` is already a list of span elements with that class so you're simply iterating through that list. You may want `a.get_text()` instead

Comment: @WStokvis I think it worked. Thank you!